# Evaluation behaves unexpectedly with machine reals are substituted for exact numbers

Tags: numerics

I ran into a bit of a weird (for me anyway) problem. Consider the bit of code below:

```
r0 = 3;
param = 40;
lambda = param π/2.;
lmax = 18;
ParallelTable[
  If[IntegerQ[2 lambda/π Sqrt[l (l + 1) - m^2]], 1, 0], {l, 1, lmax},{m, -l, l}]
```

When I evaluate this code, it should obtain an array mostly filled with 0s and a few values of 1.

However, if parameters `r0` and `param` are given as real numbers (`3.` and `40.` instead of `3` and `40`) the result is all zeroes. Why is that? Why does it matter if there are integer or real numbers given as input for a formula that contains Pi and Sqrt?

Comment: Note that `IntegerQ[1.]` is `False`, whereas `IntegerQ[1]` is `True`, and that whenever you combine real and integer numbers, the result is real. Maybe use `If[Abs[x - Round[x]] < 10^-12, ...]` instead of `IntegerQ`.

Comment: That is a great suggestion and I will try that, however in that expression there are real and integers! Pi is real, Sqrt is real. numbers `l` and `m` inside the Sqrt are integers by definition. After some more tries I realised that `r0` cand be real but not `param` or the number `2` in the expressions in the block. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Although `Pi` is real, it is an *exact* number. That is, it is *not* represented as `3.14159...`, but as the symbolic expression `Pi`. As long as it is not combined with a finite-precision number, it stays exact and Mathematica may simplify the expression to an exact integer. For example `Pi/Pi` gives `1`, not `1.`.

Comment: Btw.: Shouldn't the line `lambda = param \[Pi]/2.;` actually be `lambda = param \[Pi]/2;`? Because otherwise you'll only get zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions like `Pi` or `Sqrt[2]` are *exact* symbolic expressions. 
That is, they are **not represented by a finite string of digits**, such as `3.14159...` for `Pi`.
Therefore, Mathematica can perform *exact* arithmetic with them. E.g.

```
Pi / Pi
(* 1 *)
```

The result is the exact number `1`, and *not* the approximate real number `1.`.

`IntegerQ[expr]` checks if the head of `expr` is `Integer`. Therefore,

```
IntegerQ[1]
(* True *)
```

but

```
IntegerQ[1.]
(* False *)
```

because `Head[1.]` is `Real` and not `Integer`.
Likewise

```
Sqrt[2]^2
(* 1 *)
```

and thus

```
IntegerQ[Sqrt[2]^2]
(* True *)
```

Note that whenever you combine an exact expression with an approximate real number, you get an approximate real number. For example

```
1. Sqrt[2]
(* 1.41421 *)
```

or

```
Sqrt[2.]
(* 1.41421 *)
```

instead of

```
Sqrt[2]
(* Sqrt[2] *)
```

which remains un-evaluated, as this is an exact expression that cannot be represented by a finite string of numbers.

Comment: thank you! this clarified a lot of questions for me! I always try to avoid exact numbers unless I used them as indexes in arrays for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
IntegerQ[1.]
(* False *)
```

This is because `Head[1.]` is `Real`, not `Integer`.

```
1. \[Element] Integers
```

returns unevaluated because `1.` means *approximately* 1, so *Mathematica* can't make a reliable decision.

```
IntegerQ[Rationalize[1.]]
(* True *)
```

This works because `Rationalize` finds the nearest `Rational`, and reduces it to `Integer` if it can. This may be too fussy in practice, I don't know. Another way is:

```
isInteger[x_] := Round[x] == x
isInteger[1.]
(* True *)
```

This works because `Equal` is `True` for approximate quantities that are close enough.

Comment: thank you! you explanation is also very clear! I have now a better understanding of how mathematica handles numbers!